# Prevent regular expression from eating parts of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Some background information: I am writing a program, which allows one to analyse document's DOM tree using CSS selectors. I can't use querySelectorAll, since I need to support older browsers, it tends to be buggy even in the newest browsers and it's not powerfull enough. That means I have to write my own CSS selector engine/parser.

I have the following regular expression.

```
var expression = /([^(>\+~)\\\(\)|^(>\+~)\\\[\]]+|\([^\)]+\)|\[[^\]]+\]|\\\.)+/g;
```

It used to divide selector into sections in the following format: [ancestor, combinator, descendant]. Example usage:

```
var selector = 'div[class]>a~p';
var parts = selector.match(expression);
```

Unfortunately, the output I get is this:

```
// parts: ['div[class]', 'a', 'p'];
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
// parts: ['div[class]', '>', 'a', '~', 'p'];
```

So the problem is that I can't figure out how to prevent the expression from eating the combinators. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I must admit that even though I consider myself quite fluent with regexes, I don't have the foggiest idea about how your regex could possibly work at all. Most notably I think that you don't really know how character classes work: `[^(>\+~)\\\(\)|^(>\+~)\\\[\]]` for example matches *one* character that doesn't belong to  the collection `()[]>+~\|`...

Comment: I must admit that I'm not an expert when it comes to regular expressions. The expression I now have is actually a modified version of an expression I used for something totally different, but since it nearly worked I hoped that with small changes it would do the trick.

Comment: The original expression is nearly identical to the one I now have. The beginning was used to match commas which are not presented inside squares. In this situation the case is nearly the same, excpet comma is replaced with those combinators. Inside squares those combinators would have very different meaning in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse CSS with regular expressions it's not a regular language. There are tools for this and regex is not one. [Here's one that I found with a quick search](http://www.glazman.org/JSCSSP/)